# How to round double in XAML, WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, double, rounding

I have the following code in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XValue}" />
```

The XValue contains a lot of decimals(1952.230822830529)

I want it to contain only 2 decimals like 1952.23 and i want to do this in the XAML code.

I have searched the internet but not found a solution to my problem - so is it even to do this in XAML using string format?

Comment: what's the type of XValue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this post (also the top result on google): [How to format number of decimal places in wpf using style/template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361689/how-to-format-number-of-decimal-places-in-wpf-using-style-template)

Try one of these:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding XValue, StringFormat=N2}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding XValue, StringFormat=#,#.00}" />
```

Comment: Yeah. Voting to close - good catch on this being a duplicate question.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate and i am sorry for that. The above is the solution to my problem, thx for letting me know!

Comment: @user1093774 Not a problem, glad we could help you find your answer!

Answer (score 6):

If `XValue` is number (not `string` type) you could use

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XValue, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a XAML Converter and call Math.Round() in its Convert() method. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

Comment: I bet if you write some native code and call that via PInvoke you can make an even more complex solution for what other people have demonstrated is a simple problem ;)

Comment: True. But Silverlight 3? WP 7.0? Whatever Microsoft comes up with next?