# Multiple culture with textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, format

I'm trying to put value (double type) in textbox and i would like to get a custom format.

To explain, i put 10001.1 or 10001,1 and i would like to have 10 001,1 in my texblock.

At the moment my result is 10,001.00 i don't know how can i change the format properly.

My textblock is bind on this :

```
    private double? _Total = null;
    public double? Total
    {
        get
        {
            if (FiltreAffaire != null)
                _Total = ListeAfterFiltre.Sum(CF => CF.CommandeFournisseurLignes.Where(CFL => CFL.Affaire.Numero == FiltreAffaire.Split('-').First().Trim()).Sum(CFL => CFL.Total_HT));
            else
                return _ListeAfterFiltre.Sum(CF => CF.Montant_HT);

            return _Total;
        }
        set
        {
            _Total = value;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use [custom format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18361689/1997232). It is unclear why you call your question "Multiple culture".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `StringFormat` to get your required value... *if you are in a country that uses the comma as a decimal separator*:

```
DoubleValue = 10001.1;
```

...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DoubleValue, StringFormat={}{0:### ###.#}}" />
```

In England, this would output the following:

```
10 001.1
```

In France, this *should* output:

```
10 001,1
```

You can also do this in code using the [`NumberFormatInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = 1;
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 };
string value = DoubleValue.ToString("N", numberFormatInfo);
```

This outputs:

```
10 001,1
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `NumberFormatInfo` in markup?

Comment: I don't believe that there is one as standard, but you could create your own custom one. See the [Creating a Custom Markup Extension in WPF](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight) article for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally use something like this (on Textbox) :

```
            CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Clone();
        ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

and converter to set value.

```
ValueConverter="{StaticResource StringToDoubleConverterN3Key}"

public class StringToDoubleConverterN3 : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value).ToString("N3").Replace('.', ',');
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```