# In XAML I want to use StringFormat to display a numerical value without any rounding happening. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

So in my XAML I have this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDecimalProperty, StringFormat={}{0:#.###}}"/>
```

When the value of MyDecimalProperty is for example 5.35570256 then the TextBlock value shown is 5.356

Is there a way to have the TextBlock show 5.355 instead (i.e. to truncate the number instead rounding it) using StringFormat?

**I know I can use a Value Converter but I wanted to know if I can use StringFormat or anything else defined in the XAML to achieve the same.**

**Update**:
People keep wondering why I don't want to use a converter. Please read above in bold. Its not that I don't want to; I just wanted to know if I can do the same with StringFormat or any other XAML construct.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362876/2470362

Comment: @AbinMathew I don't see how this answers my question. From what I have observed, if the input number precision is greater than the format string defined then rounding is happening. In my example the number has 4 decimal places but the the format string has 3 placeholders. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Ok. StringFormat works for string types. so rounding is not going to work in that way. now if you need rounding you can use a converter to do that. and return the rounded value.

Comment: I think what he is asking is how to not specify the number of digits in the number.
@tolism7 Can't you just remove the StringFormat?

Comment: @GlenThomas yes you are correct. he is asking about to display the value with out rounding.

Comment: @GlenThomas I would not want to remove the StringFormat as the MyDecimalProperty can carry numbers with any precision (i.e. 8 or more) and I want to be consistent on my GUI only showing the 3 first decimal places. This is not a major issue for me or my application but it got me curious on how something like this could be achieved. I looked it up thoroughly online and I could find nothing that answers my question.... so here I am asking.

Comment: Maybe he wants a minimum of 3 decimal places, but if number is more precise then show the additional places.

Comment: Ah I think I understand. When you specify 3 decimal places, the 3rd is rounded depending on the 4th...

Comment: @GlenThomas That's it... and I am asking how to NOT have this happening

Comment: Having read the entire MSDN documentation on custom numeric format strings. It would appear that it is not possible [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: You could create a read-only property that rounds however you desire, and bind to that.

Comment: @recursive This is indeed a way to do this but it could blow up the view model if I have a few such properties. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I can use StringFormat or anything else defined in the XAML to achieve the same

StringFormat is specific to the [Binding Markup Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750413(v=vs.100).aspx) (actually the binding base [BindingBase.StringFormat Property (System.Windows.Data)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.100).aspx)) and ultimately uses the .Net string formatting such as `ToString("G3")` (see [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)) which rounds and doesn't truncate; so it is not possible to override in Xaml such features.

---

Create another property on the viewmodel which is an associated `string` type which simply parrot's the value wanted, but truncated. Then bind as such.

**ViewModel**

```
public decimal TargetDecimal
{
    get { return _TargetDecimal; }
    set { _TargetDecimal = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("TargetDecimal"); 
        OnPropertyChanged("TargetValueTruncated"); }
}

// No error checking done for example
public string TargetValueTruncated
{
  get { return Regex.Match(_TargetDecimal.ToString(), @"\d+\.\d\d\d").Value; }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetDecimal, StringFormat=Original:   {0}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetDecimal, StringFormat=Modified:   {0:#.###}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetValueTruncated, StringFormat=Truncated: {0}}"/>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: On the basis that this answer explains why StringFormat used in XAML can't do what I want to do this is the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can do this simply with using StringFormat. Is there a reason why you do not want to use a converter? (see below).

Converter:

```
public class TruncateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            double truncated;
            if (Double.TryParse(value, out truncated))
            {
                return ((double)((int)(truncated * 1000.0))) / 1000.0;
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDecimalProperty, Converter={StaticResource TruncateConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in the question, its not that I don't want to use a converter, its more of I was curious to see if the StringFormat allowed me in some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use a converter (I am not sure why, but you will have your reasons) you can consider changing the returned type of your binding source and then implementing [IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Take a look to this sample. First of all your `MyDecimalProperty` should not return a decimal anymore. You should change it in order to return a `TruncatedDecimal`. Here its code:

```
public class TruncatedDecimal : IFormattable
{
    private decimal value;

    public TruncatedDecimal(decimal doubleValue)
    {
        value = doubleValue;
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        int decimalDigits = Int32.Parse(format.Substring(1));
        decimal mult = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimalDigits);
        decimal trucatedValue = Math.Truncate(value * mult) / mult;

        return trucatedValue.ToString(format, formatProvider);
    }
}
```

Now in your XAML your can use the format string that you need:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}N5}" Margin="5" FontSize="20" />
```

So, for example, if the DataContext is set in this way:

```
DataContext = new TruncatedDecimal(new Decimal(.4997888869));
```

You will see **0.49978**. I hope this solution will be suitable for your needs and can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is an interesting approach but I consider the converter a simpler solution because it does not involve changing the property type in my view model. Having said that, I have highlighted in the question why I am not using a converter in the first place as it seems people miss that part. I just wanted to learn if this could be done straight in XAML with StringFormat or something else.