# How to always show three digits after the comma

Tags: c#, wpf

Lets say i have a TextBox. When i write 0.5 i want it to Show it as 0.500 automatically.

My Problem is that as soon as the Digits after the comma are 0 they get cut off.

Example

0.5 -> 0.500

0.51 -> 0.510

The Change itself will happen in the LostFocus Event (Excel like calculation).

I Need fixed 3 Digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format number of decimal places in wpf using style/template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361689/how-to-format-number-of-decimal-places-in-wpf-using-style-template)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

```
 var output = string.Format("{0:#,0.000}", value));
```

Ex:

```
 float[] values = new float[] { 0.5f, 0.51f, 0.51234f };
 foreach( var v in values)
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,0.000}", v));            
 Console.ReadKey();
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way just to Change from string to string because  i dont really Need it on console.

Comment: you don't need to use console. this is just an example! See this line  string output = string.Format("{0:#,0.000}", value));

Comment: works so far thank you. I'll test it a bit than accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in WPF, you can do it in XAML :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Length, StringFormat={}{0:#000}}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
```

Comment: Does not work for me. If i type into the TextBox nothing changes.

Comment: ok sorry for me, I just saw you use TextBox, and I use it for TextBlock... In the case of a Textbox I see it more difficult as you may be able to edit it too.