# xaml StringFormat that accepts "," as a decimal point

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

We have code for a textbox looking like this:

```
 <TextBox  Width="120" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding xxxxx, StringFormat=\{0:F2\}%}"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
```

The problem is that the user insists on it being necessary that they can use **","** as a decimal point since that is the way it has been done over the years.

As it is now the formating just skips it so if you type 22,33% it makes it 2233%.

Is the any way I can make the StringFormat accept both **"."** and **","** as decimal points, or do I have to format it in some other way (I'm new to WPF and xaml so might have missed something obvious)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format number of decimal places in wpf using style/template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361689/how-to-format-number-of-decimal-places-in-wpf-using-style-template)

Comment: Unfortunately not, from what I understand atleast. I could put a regex or something in the viewmodel though instead of using StringFormat

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the value programmatically with a converter:

```
public class FormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo s_cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de");

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        ((decimal)value).ToString("F2") + "%";

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string a = value.ToString();
        decimal d;
        if ((a?.Contains(",") == true && decimal.TryParse(a, NumberStyles.Any, s_cultureInfo, out d))
            || decimal.TryParse(a, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
            return d;

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

The above sample implementation uses a culture that supports `,` when trying to convert a `string` that contains a comma to a `decimal`.

This is how you would use it in your XAML markup:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FormatConverter x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBox  Width="120" Grid.Column="2"
          Text="{Binding xxxxx, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"  />
```