# How to modify the precision of WPF DateGridTextColumn when program is running

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting

The numerical value in WPF DataGridTextColumn can be bound to background data:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Test1}"
```

However, the StringFormat property can only be set once and cannot be bound to a variable in background code:

```
StringFormat=N4
```

I want to modify the precision of the values in the entire datagrid by setting a value in the combobox control and clicking "OK" button.

In Winform, I can do like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format=$"N{Acc}";
```

There is a similar question here: [How to format number of decimal places in wpf using style/template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361689/how-to-format-number-of-decimal-places-in-wpf-using-style-template). The method can make the precision determined at runtime, but it still does not seem to have the function of modification. It may also be that I didn't fully understand the first answer in that I am a beginner of WPF.

Then I tried like this:
In cs:

```
  public class TableItem:INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public TableItem(double test1, double test2) {
      this.test1 = test1;
      this.test2 = test2;
    }

    private int acc;
    public int Acc {
      get => acc;
      set {
        acc = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgsnameof(Test1Str)));
      }
    }

    private double test1;
    public double Test1 {
      get => test1;
      set {
        test1 = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Test1Str)));
      }
    }

    public string Test1Str => test1.ToString($"N{acc}");

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
```

In xaml:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Test1Str}" Header="Test1" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

This seems to meet the requirements, but I feel this is not the right way. Can anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Now my C# programming skills have improved a bit, so I will briefly answer my own question. A relatively elegant approach is to use "MultiBinding", which binds data and decimal places, as the "ConverterParameter" of a regular "Binding" cannot bind local variables.
If anyone has questions about this, you can ask me again.